# GridSearchCV: Scoring does not use the chosen XGBRegressor score method

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, gridsearchcv

Scikit-learn GridSearchCV is used for hyper parameter tuning of XGBRegressor models. Independent of specified *eval_metric* in XGBRegressor().fit() the same score values are produced by GridSearchCV. On https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html it says for the parameter *scoring*: "If None, the estimator’s score method is used." This does not happen. Always get same value. **How can I get results corresponding to XGBRegressor *eval_metric*?**

This sample code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, KFold
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import xgboost as xgb

rng = np.random.RandomState(31337)

boston = load_boston()
y = boston['target']
X = boston['data']

kf = KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=42)
folds = list(kf.split(X))

xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror', verbose=False)
reg = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb_model, 
                   param_grid= {'max_depth': [2], 'n_estimators': [50]}, 
                   cv=folds,
                   verbose=False)

reg.fit(X, y, **{'eval_metric': 'mae', 'verbose': False})
print('GridSearchCV mean(mae)?:  ', reg.cv_results_['mean_test_score'])
# -----------------------------------------------
reg.fit(X, y, **{'eval_metric': 'rmse', 'verbose': False})
print('GridSearchCV mean(rmse)?: ', reg.cv_results_['mean_test_score'])
print("----------------------------------------------------")

xgb_model.set_params(**{'max_depth': 2, 'n_estimators': 50})
xgb_model.fit(X[folds[0][0],:],y[folds[0][0]], eval_metric='mae', 
              eval_set = [(X[folds[0][0],:],y[folds[0][0]])], verbose=False)
print('XGBRegressor 0-mae:', xgb_model.evals_result()['validation_0']['mae'][-1])
xgb_model.fit(X[folds[0][1],:],y[folds[0][1]], eval_metric='mae', 
              eval_set = [(X[folds[0][1],:],y[folds[0][1]])], verbose=False)
print('XGBRegressor 1-mae:', xgb_model.evals_result()['validation_0']['mae'][-1])

xgb_model.fit(X[folds[0][0],:],y[folds[0][0]], eval_metric='rmse', 
              eval_set = [(X[folds[0][0],:],y[folds[0][0]])], verbose=False)
print('XGBRegressor 0-rmse:', xgb_model.evals_result()['validation_0']['rmse'][-1])
xgb_model.fit(X[folds[0][1],:],y[folds[0][1]], eval_metric='rmse', 
              eval_set = [(X[folds[0][1],:],y[folds[0][1]])], verbose=False)
print('XGBRegressor 1-rmse:', xgb_model.evals_result()['validation_0']['rmse'][-1])
```

returns (the numbers above the line should have been an average of those below the line)

```
GridSearchCV mean(mae)?:   [0.70941007]
GridSearchCV mean(rmse)?:  [0.70941007]
----------------------------------------------------
XGBRegressor 0-mae: 1.273626
XGBRegressor 1-mae: 1.004947
XGBRegressor 0-rmse: 1.647694
XGBRegressor 1-rmse: 1.290872
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: What you're returned is so called `R2` or coefficient of determination. This is the default scoring metric for `XGBRegressor` `score` function that is picked up by `GridSearchCV` if `scoring=None`

Compare the results with explicitly coding `scoring`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, r2_score, mean_squared_error
xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror', verbose=False)

reg = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb_model, scoring=make_scorer(r2_score),
                   param_grid= {'max_depth': [2], 'n_estimators': [50]}, 
                   cv=folds,
                   verbose=False)

reg.fit(X, y)
reg.best_score_
0.7333542105472226
```

with those with `scoring=None`:

```
reg = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb_model, scoring=None,
                   param_grid= {'max_depth': [2], 'n_estimators': [50]}, 
                   cv=folds,
                   verbose=False)

reg.fit(X, y)
reg.best_score_
0.7333542105472226
```

If you read `GridSearchCV` [docstrings](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L864) :

> estimator : estimator object.
>           This is assumed to implement the scikit-learn estimator interface.
>           Either estimator needs to provide a `score` function,
>           or `scoring` must be passed.

At this point you would want to check docs for `xgb_model.score?`:

> Signature: xgb_model.score(X, y, sample_weight=None)
>   Docstring:
>   Return the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.

So, with the help of those documents, if you do not like `XGBRegressor`'s default `R2` score function, provide your scoring function explicitly to `GridSearchCV`

E.g. if you want `RMSE` you may do:

```
reg = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb_model,  
                   scoring=make_scorer(mean_squared_error, squared=False),
                   param_grid= {'max_depth': [2], 'n_estimators': [50]}, 
                   cv=folds,
                   verbose=False)

reg.fit(X, y)
reg.best_score_
4.618242594168436
```

Comment: The gist of the answer was you can't use specified scorer from xgboost. If scorer=None, it's default scorer that gets picked up. And I explained why it so.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I have probably simplified my question too much. 

I am aware that you in GridSearchCV can specify scoring=make_scorer(), using a metric from sklearn.metrics. If XGBoost uses eval_metric=‘mae’ I hope to avoid redefining MAE in GridSearchCV scoring=make_scorer().

I really want to run XGBRegressor with {‘objective’: ‘reg:tweedie’, ‘eval_metric’: ‘tweedie-nloglik’}. Sklearn.metrics does not have this metric. I do not think I can write my own scoring function for that. **How can I get tweedie-nloglik as scoring output from GridSearchCV?**

Comment: As I clearly stated this in my answer, with links to the docs and sklearn source code, the custom scoring function won't be picked by GridSearchCV. These are just 2 different packages with different source code that does not have access to each other source base. You have to write it your own. So, if you do want it, your real question is "how to write tweedie-nloglik as scoring function".